# install libRmath on Mac OS X with Homebrew

Tags: r, macos, homebrew

I would like to install `libRmath.dylib` on Mac OS X (Mavericks) preferably with Homebrew since I already use this package manager.

I did not find a formula for `libRmath`, but I did find a formula for `R` so I tried to extend it with (see entire file at end):

```
# Also build libRmath.dylib
system "cd src/nmath/standalone"
system "make"
system "make install"
system "cd ../../.."
lib.mkpath
ln_s prefix+"R.framework/Resources/lib/", lib
```

The commands `./configure; cd src/nmath/standalone; make` do create `libRmath.dylib` if I execute them manually. But not using `brew install r`. I cannot find `libRmath.dylib` in `Cellar`. What am I doing wrong? (Note that I am new to Ruby and Homebrew's formula.)

Below is the entire file.

```
require 'formula'

class RDownloadStrategy < SubversionDownloadStrategy
  def stage
    quiet_safe_system 'cp', '-r', @clone, Dir.pwd
    Dir.chdir cache_filename
  end
end

class R < Formula
  homepage 'http://www.r-project.org/'
  url 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.1.1.tar.gz'
  mirror 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.1.1.tar.gz'
  sha1 'e974ecc92e49266529e8e791e02a80c75e50b696'

  head do
    url 'https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk', :using => RDownloadStrategy
    depends_on :tex
  end

  option "without-accelerate", "Build without the Accelerate framework (use Rblas)"
  option 'without-check', 'Skip build-time tests (not recommended)'
  option 'without-tcltk', 'Build without Tcl/Tk'

  depends_on :fortran
  depends_on 'readline'
  depends_on 'gettext'
  depends_on 'libtiff'
  depends_on 'jpeg'
  depends_on 'cairo'
  depends_on :x11 => :recommended
  depends_on 'valgrind' => :optional
  depends_on 'openblas' => :optional

  # This is the same script that Debian packages use.
  resource 'completion' do
    url 'https://rcompletion.googlecode.com/svn-history/r28/trunk/bash_completion/R', :using => :curl
    version 'r28'
    sha1 'af734b8624b33f2245bf88d6782bea0dc5d829a4'
  end

  def install
    args = [
      "--prefix=#{prefix}",
      "--with-aqua",
      "--with-libintl-prefix=#{Formula['gettext'].prefix}",
      "--enable-R-framework",
    ]

    if build.with? 'valgrind'
      args << '--with-valgrind-instrumentation=2'
      ENV.Og
    end

    if build.with? "openblas"
      args << "--with-blas=-L#{Formula["openblas"].opt_lib} -lopenblas" << "--with-lapack"
    elsif build.with? "accelerate"
      args << "--with-blas=-framework Accelerate" << "--with-lapack"
      # Fall back to Rblas without-accelerate or -openblas
    end

    args << '--without-tcltk' if build.without? 'tcltk'
    args << '--without-x' if build.without? 'x11'

    # Also add gettext include so that libintl.h can be found when installing packages.
    ENV.append "CPPFLAGS", "-I#{Formula['gettext'].include}"

    # Pull down recommended packages if building from HEAD.
    system './tools/rsync-recommended' if build.head?

    system "./configure", *args
    system "make"
    ENV.deparallelize # Serialized installs, please
    system "make check 2>&1 | tee make-check.log" if build.with? 'check'
    system "make install"

    # Also build libRmath.dylib
    system "cd src/nmath/standalone"
    system "make"
    system "make install"
    system "cd ../../.."
    lib.mkpath
    ln_s prefix+"R.framework/Resources/lib/", lib

    # Link binaries and manpages from the Framework
    # into the normal locations
    bin.mkpath
    man1.mkpath

    ln_s prefix+"R.framework/Resources/bin/R", bin
    ln_s prefix+"R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript", bin
    ln_s prefix+"R.framework/Resources/man1/R.1", man1
    ln_s prefix+"R.framework/Resources/man1/Rscript.1", man1

    bash_completion.install resource('completion')

    prefix.install 'make-check.log' if build.with? 'check'

  end

  test do
    (testpath / 'test.R').write('print(1+1);')
    system "r < test.R --no-save"
    system "rscript test.R"
  end

  def caveats; <<-EOS.undent
    To enable rJava support, run the following command:
      R CMD javareconf JAVA_CPPFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
    EOS
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Formula `r`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/r.rb) now has the option `with-librmath-only` which only builds the standalone libRmath library.